# Form in MySQL shows no result?

Tags: php, html, forms, url, isset

I'm trying to create a form that when submitted will run a query through MySQL. However when I test it, nothing happens, though I receive no error. I have another isset on the same page, with a different form.

Here is the php bit:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$owner = $_POST['id'];

$get = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wolves WHERE name = '$owner'");
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($get);
echo $result['name'];

}
```

And here is the form:

```
<?php
echo 
"
<form action=test.php name=form2>
Id: <select name='id'>
";
while ($own = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
{
echo "<option value='" . $own['name'] . "'>" . $own['name'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select><input type=submit name=submit value=Submit!></form>";
?>
```

The proper values show up in the URL when the form is submitted but the php does not seem to work at all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: <form action=test.php name=form2 method="post">. You forgot to mention the method type

Comment: @Christopher i guess you should mention that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Mention Method POST In Your Form**

Check whether the form submit coming inside your expected loop or not,

Then please use while loop inside form submit loop for getting your expected value as follows,

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $owner = $_POST['id'];    
    $get = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wolves WHERE name = '$owner'");
    while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)) {
        echo $result['name'];
    }    
}
```

Comment: please check echo with some constant value.. so we can check whether its coming inside loop or not... "echo 'test'"... if not please execute query in phpmyadmin/sqlyog and check it returns value of not...

Answer (score 0):

> The proper values show up in the URL when the form is submitted

means data passing through url, your can get through GET method, else  mention `post` as a method in form

`<form action=test.php name=form2 method=post>`

Answer (score 0):

You have not set the `method` for the the form. That means the values will be sent to the server using `get` method. In you php you can then access those variables using the `$_GET` **super global**.

What you have done is, submitted the form using `get` method and trying to access the values using `$_POST` **superglobal**, which is empty and your sever returns false for `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`.

Change the `method` for the form to `post` and then re-run the code.

Answer (score 0):

you must have to take `method="post"` in form

```
<form action="test.php" name="form2" method="post">
```